# Como activar un textbox al escribir ciertos codigos en otro textbox?

Tags: php, javascript

Espero me puedan ayudar, lo que yo quiero es tener dos textbox y que si escribo unos código en el textbox1 active el textbox2 crear un tipo de condición donde pueda agregar que códigos son los que pueden habilitar el segundo textbox

por ejemplo:
en este caso se puede decir que el 2, 5 y 7

textbox1= 1
textbox2 = bloqueado

textbox1=5
textbox2= habilitado

y una vez habilitado pueda meter datos para guardar

Lo que tengo es una estructura simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <center><h1>PRUEBA</h1>

        <label>Textbox1</label>
        <input type="text" name="text1" required><br><br>

        <label>Textbox2</label>
        <input type="text" name="text2" disabled required>      
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

solo que no se como hacer esa función

Comment: Hola, agrega el código que tienes hasta ahora y te ayudamos con gusto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede dar click en **Ejecutar** para correr la respuesta propuesta, cuando el **textbox1** tiene el valor 2, 5 o 7 el **textbox2** se **deshabilita**.

```js
cambioTextBox1 = function() {
  var textbox1 = document.getElementById("textbox1");
  var textbox2 = document.getElementById("textbox2");
  
  var valorTextBox1 = textbox1.value;
  
  if(
    valorTextBox1 == "2" ||
    valorTextBox1 == "5" ||
    valorTextBox1 == "7"
  ) {
    textbox2.disabled = true;
  } else {
    textbox2.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox1" onChange="cambioTextBox1()">
<input type="text" id="textbox2">
```

Comment: gracias amigo! lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```js
const $inputActivador = document.getElementById('input-activador')
const $inputText = document.getElementById('input-text')
const validators = ['2', '5', '7']

$inputActivador.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    $inputText.disabled = !(validators.find(validator => validator === e.target.value))
})
```

```html
<label>Textbox1</label>
<input id="input-activador" type="text" name="text1" required><br><br>

<label>Textbox2</label>
<input id="input-text" type="text" name="text2" disabled required>
```